# prove this inequality related to probability and information theory

Tags: probability, inequality, proof-writing, entropy

How do I prove this?
I'm thinking I should use Jensen's inequality somehow.

$$\sum_K p_k(1-p_k) \le -\sum_K p_k\log p_k$$

The assumption that $\sum_K p_k=1$ holds.

Comment: Is there an assumption that $\sum_K p_k=1$? Also, use `\log` to type the logarithm correctly; and `\le` to get the nonstrict inequality sign.

Comment: If $0<p_k<1$, I dont' understand, as $1-p_k>0$ and $\log (p_k)<0$...? Anyway, don't forget : $log(x)<x-1$

Comment: @Thursday yes, the assumption holds. Thanks for the formatting help.

Comment: @PierreAlvarez Yes, I thought that I should use that somehow, but with the summation still remaining on the left hand side, Im unsure of how to eliminate it.

Comment: Shouldn't there be a "minus" sign on the right side of the inequality ?

Comment: @PierreAlvarez Yes. Thanks for the correction!

Comment: Then you just have to use my first comment

Comment: @Raaj : Please look at my edits.  The utter bizarreness of the way people write MathJax code on this site continually amazes me.  Was the lack of space between $\log$ and $p_k$ not conspicuous to you?  Things like that distract me from the content of the question.

Comment: The bizarre people like me learn from excellent people like you. Thank you for your help. Much appreciated. I will think of you before writing spaces for every question from now on.Good day sir.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained in the comments, the inequality $$\sum_kp_k(1-p_k)\lt\sum_kp_k\log p_k$$ cannot hold since the LHS is nonnegative and the RHS is nonpositive.

To show that $$\sum_kp_k(1-p_k)\leqslant-\sum_kp_k\log p_k,$$ note that, for every positive $x$, $$1-x\leqslant-\log x.$$

Comment: absolutely. Monotonicity. However, I was trying to deduce this from the given problem. It looks like starting with it itself is easier.

Thank you!

Comment: Please could you also show 1 - x \leq log x?

Comment: @samthebest You first: how do you think one could prove that?

Comment: @Did, case bash it. Its clear for x \leq 0 and x \geq 1, but Im stuck stuck for x \in (0, 1).

Comment: Well i say "clear", first case is using the fact that e^y \gt 0 for any real y, and second case is using some basic calculus. Its certainly not trivial enough to just say "note that", so not a full proof really.

Comment: @samthebest Let us leave aside the unwarranted assertions about what (you think) a full proof should be, shall we, and let us stick to the maths: can you prove the inequality for the regime where we use it in the post, that is, for $x$ in $(0,1)$? (By the way, I do not know what you are referring to with your "Its clear for x \leq 0" since for $x\lt0$ the inequality is absurd.)

Comment: A sequence of sentences where each is the application of a rule of inference on previous sentences in the sequence or on a sentence from some ZFC, PA (or similar), is a proof. That is not what "I think", it is not subjective, let's *leave aside accusations unwarranted assertions about what you think* I'm asking for. Now, in practice one starts from not an axiom scheme, but some prerequisites defined by the course. Since you have not provided a reference to a proof to your "note" nor proved it, it is neither a formal nor pragmatic proof, as per the question.

Comment: Furthermore given that the assertion is a single trivial application of substitution of your note, it's basically the crux of the proof and should not be left out.

Comment: @samthebest Blablablah... Can you prove it?

Comment: Yes, using calculus and rearranging as e^(x -  1) - x \ge 0. One can show x = 1 is a minima.

Comment: @samthebest End of story.